# vim color scheme breaks when using tmux

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, vim, colors, tmux

I am using Ubuntu 18 LTS, gnome-terminal, with vim 8.0. When I am not using a color scheme, vim looks the same when launched inside or outside of tmux:
[image: Vim_Comparison_Without_Color_Scheme]

However, when I use a color scheme (in this case gruvbox), vim will look odd inside of tmux:
[image: Vim_Comparison_With_Color_Scheme]

How can I fix this?

Here is some background info:

My `.vimrc`:

```
" Don't try to be vi compatible
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

"Colorscheme gruvbox https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox
Plugin 'morhetz/gruvbox'

" Language support pack
Plugin 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'

call vundle#end()

" Indenting https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10124/what-is-the-difference-between-filetype-plugin-indent-on-and-filetype-indent
filetype plugin indent on

" set Vim-specific sequences for RGB colors (fixes color bug)
let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"

" fixes glitch? in colors when using vim with tmux
set background=dark
set t_Co=256

" make colors look better
set termguicolors 

" enable italic text
let g:gruvbox_italic = '1' 

"Set colorscheme to gruvbox
colorscheme gruvbox

" Turn on syntax highlighting
syntax on

" Show line numbers
set number

" Show file stats
set ruler

" Blink cursor on error instead of beeping (grr)
set visualbell

" Enable Mouse
set mouse=a

" show tabs as 4 spaces
set tabstop=4

" convert tabs to spaces
set expandtab 

" stop line wrapping (or something similar)
set nowrap 

" make side scrolling less jumpy
set sidescroll=1

" Enter inserts new line in normal mode
nmap <S-Enter> O<Esc>
nmap <CR> o<Esc>
```

I also uncommented a line in my bashrc:

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes
```

Typing "$TERM" in and out of tmux returns the value "screen-256color".

Also, here is my `.tmux.conf`:

```
# remap prefix from 'C-b' to 'C-a'
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-a
bind-key C-a send-prefix

# split panes using | and -
bind \ split-window -h
bind - split-window -v
unbind '"'
unbind %

# switch panes using Alt-arrow without prefix
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D

# Enable mouse mode (tmux 2.1 and above)
set -g mouse on


#256 Color Support?
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with putty > ubuntu, centos, macos > tmux [2.7,3.1] > vim 8.1

```
$ tmux -2 # force tmux to use 256 colors.
```